# Wind force field only works in the center of the scene

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

I am playing with cloth waving in the wind and I have the problem with positioning the force field (wind). It would only affect the mesh (cloth) geometry if the mesh is positioned in the center of the scene. Put in other words, if I move the force field to a different location (so that it could not affect the mesh) the mesh still waves in the wind. If I position both the force field and the mesh to a different location so that the force field would be aimed at the mesh, the mesh is not affected by the force at all. Waving only works when the mesh is positioned in the absolute scene center no matter the actual position of the force field. I am attaching the .blend file where you will find the cloth in the absolute center and the displaced wind source. The cloth is still waving. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Wind force field gives a constant force in a single direction. It's like a Sun light but emitting force instead of light, so You can imagine it as an endless flat plane emitting force.It's a global force. You can change only direction of it.
I checked your file and everything seams to be ok. It worked wherever I put cloth or wind source, so when You noticed it's not working You must've not back the animation to start position.

Comment: Thank you for testing my .blend file. This is really strange, because when I move the flag it is really not effected by the wind at all and I believe I do back the animation to start position. Is it possible that the version of Blender I am using is somehow buggy? I have recorded a video of what I see, you can check it here: https://youtu.be/GVVtPkkI0ds

Comment: Strange Indeed. Someone with Mac should test it. I'm running on Ubuntu and was testing the file on Blender 2.77, and everything worked fine.